# OCMock throwing NSInternalInconsistencyException when parameters are not the ones expected

Tags: ios, tdd, ocunit, ocmock

I'm setting up a mock object for a delegate object, to check that when  the URL is nil, the delegate method is called with nil as parameters.

When the `FileDownloadOperation` behave as expected,the test pass, which is fine.

When the `FileDownloadOperation` doesn't call the delegate method, the test fails as expected.

But when the `FileDownloadOperation` calls the delegate method with something else than `nil`, instead of failing, the test crashes and no other tests are executed because `OCMock` throws :

'NSInternalInconsistencyException' reason: 'OCMockObject[FileDownloadOperationTest]: unexpected method invoked: data:<> forURL:nil

```
  -(void) testNilURL{
      // 1. Create an operation
      FileDownloadOperation * anOp = [[FileDownloadOperation alloc]init];
      // 2. set a nil URL
      anOp.URL = nil;
      // 3. set a mock delegate
      id mockDelegate = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[self class]];
      [[mockDelegate expect] data:[OCMArg isNil] forURL:[OCMArg isNil]];
      anOp.delegate = mockDelegate;
      // 4. launch operation
      [anOp main];
      // 5. ASSERT mock delegate is called with nil data
      STAssertNoThrow([mockDelegate verify], @"Delegate should be called with nil data and nil URL");
      [anOp release];
    }
```

Is it the expected behaviour ? or am I doing something wrong ?
thanks !

Comment: This was solved in the iOS 5.0 simulator, now OCMock simply reports test failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCMock throws exceptions to report mismatches, trusting OCUnit to catch and report any exceptions. But [due to a bug in the iOS Simulator](http://openradar.appspot.com/8081169), unit tests are unable to catch exceptions, and so simply crash.

(I'm currently writing a new mocking framework that works around this problem by not relying on exceptions.)